# Does Anyone Know How to Use Wine Securely?

Tags: wine

I switched over to Ubuntu and wanted to play some of my older Steam games such as Star Wars Battlefront 2 (2005) using Wine. I know Wine can cause security issues if not installed and used properly which will bother me since I take security really seriously. Does anyone know how I could do all of this properly? Thanks!

Comment: Are you saying that you believe the normal installation of Wine from apt or the Ubuntu Software Center to be insecure? If so, what leads you to that conclusion?

Comment: See also https://forum.winehq.org/viewtopic.php?t=15302

Comment: If you are playing with steam then you can install it directly in linux.

Answer (score 0):

You're best off using a program like PlayOnLinux which containerizes your installations, and gives you the best WINE version to run each one. Would be helpful for Battlefront. When you close one of these containers it terminates all the programs running in it. That's not bad for a security standpoint, but your WINE programs would have access to everything in your home folder.

I suppose if you were super paranoid, you would set up AppArmor and isolate your system, like your Home directory from your WINE applications. If you're interested in spending hours trying to do this, [you could set up AppArmor](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AppArmor) and use a [profile like this one (have to edit for PlayOnLinux to work)](https://github.com/mk-fg/apparmor-profiles/blob/master/profiles/usr.bin.wine). It's up to you how far you want to go.

There's also a middle ground with Firejail. You could just run PlayOnLinux in firejail and it should isolate it and the WINE processes from your system.